# How to make sure that ReactDOM.createPortal in App component runs in while I mount the same in my test case?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-dom

I tried running testing App component by mounting first , but it throws error : Target container is not DOM element , pointing to 2nd parameter ' header ' in ReactDOM.createPortal function...so , how can I make sure that header-named element is there after mounting ??? I tried attachTo by making some document.createElement to make header element, but did not help...Please help ...

react and jest with latest versions would be fine as enviroments

App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';

it('render app', () => {
    const rendered = mount(<App />);
});
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const headerProp = document.getElementById('header');
console.log("headerProp in App.js :: " , headerProp);
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(<div id='cntr'>HIIIIIIIII</div> , headerProp)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

index.html

```
....
.....
<body>
    <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div class="jp-react-cmp" id="header">
    </div>
    <div class="jp-react-cmp" id="banner">
    </div>
    <div class="jp-react-cmp" id="root">
    </div>

...
....
```

error   , after   npm run test::

```
Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.

       8 |   return (
       9 |     <div className="App">
    > 10 |       {ReactDOM.createPortal(<div id='cntr'>HIIIIIIIII</div> , headerProp)}
         |                 ^
      11 |     </div>
      12 |   );
      13 | }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want for this portal? As I can see, the issue is maybe the provided "header" argument is NOT a valid DOM node. Also, I think it's not best to put that in the state.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you provided an invalid **header** as an argument to  **createPortal**.

A simple example of using **ReactDOM.createPortal** would be:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function MyPortal() {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div>Content</div>,
    document.body
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyPortal />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: please re-check , I actually have header reference from index.html , where my App renders into root element like ::: `ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('root'))`; and there is header div in index.html too , like shown above ...@Jojo Tutor

Comment: can you log the value of "header" ? make sure this is NOT null value.

Comment: No , actually whole app runs , ...currently there is some bug(not related to createPortal) in latest dev version , so I will log value of header after bug resolves

Comment: Hey @Jojo Tutor  , I ran a different bug producing code and got output on console as ===> headerProp in App.js ::  <div id=​"header">(Whatever Child I pass into createPortal)​</div>

Comment: Hey @Jojo Tutor , did you find any luck in replicating the issue with the code I updated , and getting solution?

Comment: No, could you please create a sample on https://codesandbox.io, where you replicate this issue? It's much easier for me to see if you have it.

Comment: https://github.com/SiddheshSutar/react-app.git :::: hey Jojo Tutor ,  try this git clone to you local and try...there might be some enzyme dependancy not found , so please install afterwards

Comment: @siddheshsutar, change this line from "const headerProp = document.getElementById('headerProp');" ==>> "const headerProp = document.getElementById('header');"

Comment: ..Sorry pal , but it did not solve the problem ..I have updated the git repository having the error causing code